# Show latest records

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to show only the last updated data as indicated below:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/HPbE5fS.png]

Comment: Have you tried using a VBA script to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is same as pnuts:

Extract a unique list of the Harry Potter entries. For example by selecting that column (assumed to be ColumnA), DATA > Sort & Filter, Advanced, Copy to another location, check Unique records only and select appropriate values for List range: and Copy to:.

Say this list is now in E2:E4 and your original list is in A2:C6:
In cell F2, get the latest dates with the below formula -- USE CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER for these:

```
=MAX(IF(($A$2:$A$6=E2),($C$2:$C$6)))
```

In cell G2, get the value associated with the date and the book with the below formula -- USE CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER again:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$6,MATCH($E2,IF($C$2:$C$6=$F2,$A$2:$A$6),0))
```